# this in Object methods does not reference on Object but on tag that function is bound to

Tags: javascript

```
MyObject = function() {
  this.a = "a";
  this.func = function() {
      this.a = "b";
      console.log(this); 
  }

}
.....
m = new MyObject();
$(li).bind('click',m.func);
```

I want: `this` in this.func references on the surrounding MyObject object.
I get: `this` references on `<li>` (thats what the console logs).

Answer (score 0):

> Use [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind), *The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.*

**Note:** Wrap `li` in quotes

```js
var MyObject = function() {
  this.a = "a";
  this.func = function() {
    this.a = "b";
    console.log(this);
  }
}
var m = new MyObject();
$('li').on('click', m.func.bind(m));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```